# redirect link between smarty and frontController

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I have a tpl-file which contains the display of my prestashop hook and I would like, via a button to call a function of the front controller, only I can't do it probably because of the url, anyone have an idea? My function redirection() can just redirect the link to te log-in page. Thank youuuuu

my tpl files in view/templates/hook

```
<div class="block-content">
    {* variable simple *}
    <h2 class="title2">{$title}</h2>
    {* recherche la value d'un tableau multidimensionnel en se basant sur sa key*}
    <h3>Bonjour {$name.firstname} {$name.lastname}</h3>
    {* recherche la key en fonction de la value du tableau *}
    {if {$age.Guillaume} > 18}
        <p>Client majeur</p>
    {else}
        <p>Client mineur</p>
    {/if}
    {* recherche l'index 1 dans le tableau *}
    <p>Vous avez le numéro {$number[1]} qui vous est assigné</p>

    {* traduction directement dans le back-office *}
    <button><a class="controller_link" href="modules/mymodule/controllers/front/display.php?redirection">{l s='Join the Controller' mod='mymodule'}</a></button>
</div>
```

and my front controller in controller/front/display.php

```
<?php
/**
 * <ModuleClassName> => Mymodule
 * <FileName> => Display
 * Format expected: <ModuleClassName><FileName>ModuleFrontController
 */
class MymoduleDIsplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate('modules/mymodule/views/templates/hook/displayleftcolumnproduct.tpl');
    }
    public function redirection()
    {
        header('Location: https://php74.localhost/prestashop/nous-contacter');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to generate a URL to your module `FrontController`, for example:

`$this->context->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display', ['action' => 'redirection'])`

in your `initContent` method, you might do something like:

```
if (Tools::getValue('action') === 'redirection') {
    $this->redirection();
}
```